# Sencha Touch: Display Image from Database

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, base64

I am new to Sencha Touch, I am trying to display image in a view. The source of the image is coming in a field of my model and is in base64 string format. I need to assign this field to the image src. When I try to set a static base 64 content in the image it works fine but when i am trying to assign dynamically via assigning the field , the view is blank.

Please see the code below

The Image base64 based content is coming in the field "Attachment"

My view code

```
 Ext.define('TechHelp.view.ViewAttachment',
            {
                xtype : 'viewattachment',
                  extend : "Ext.form.Panel",
                requires :"Ext.form.FieldSet" ,

      config : {
                    //styleHtmlContent : true,
                    scrollable : 'vertical',
                    title : 'Attachments',
    items : [{
        xtype : "image",
       name : 'attachment',
       src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+'Attachment',
           height:'100px',
       width: '100px'
}, ]
 },

 });
```

My Model Code

Ext.define('TechHelp.model.Attachment', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
config: {
    // define the fields. the default type is string

    fields:// ['customerId','FirstName'],
          [{name:'AttachmentId'},
           {name:'TicketId'},
           {name:'Attachment'},
           {name:'FileName'},
           ],

},
```

});

Please help.

Comment: i'm super confused on this one.  To use a model you need a store which I don't see in your code.  Also an image isn't an object that you can attach a store to, so the methodology you are taking wouldn't even work.  If you are storing all your base64 data in a store you would have to extract the exact record and push the value in with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably set data to the view, then use tpl to print the values:

controller:

```
var itemView = Ext.create('TechHelp.view.ViewAttachment');
itemView.setRecord(record);
```

view:

```
config : {
    scrollable : 'vertical',
    title : 'Attachments',
    tpl: '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{Attachment}" />'
    ....
},

updateRecord: function(record) {
    if (record) this.setData(record.data);
}
```

hope it helps-